# Blocking operation in custom SWT component

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, swt

**What is the best way to run long operations within custom SWT components?**

**Objective:** I want to build a mail state indicator with SWT. Basically, it should constantly poll a service and display an image depending on the state flag that is returned (for sake of simplicity, lets say `MailState.NO_MAILS` or `MailState.NEW_MAILS`).

**Problem:** I'm aware of the fact, that I should not run a blocking operation in the SWT GUI thread.

So what is the best way to make my component either poll a service asynchronously every x seconds or (maybe) use a blocking `Future` without making my interface freeze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Display.timerExec` to run a `Runnable` after a given number of milliseconds:

```
Display.getDefault().timerExec(millisec, runnable);
```

Note: The runnable runs in the user interface thread.

This does not repeat so you need to call `timerExec` again to set up the next run.

If your task will block for a long time you will have to run it in a separate thread. You can use `Display.asyncExec` to update the user interface from that thread:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(runnable);
```

where `runnable` is a `Runnable` that will be executed in the user interface thread as soon as possible.

Comment: Won't this block the UI thread then, if my operation lasts very long?

Comment: Yes it will, you will have to start a separate thread for anything that is long running.

Comment: So, this was my initial concern. What is the best way to tailor all this together? My idea was to start a thread and make it call a ``Future`` that blocks until a response is received. Then I would stop the thread and update my user interface. I'm still unsure about the entire thread handling, though (UI thread vs. custom thread).

Comment: Added info about Display.asyncExec that you can use in a background thread.